# Measuring the time it takes for a function to run and complete in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.4.1, I'm trying to measure how long it takes for a function to run and complete then recording it. I'm currently doing it this like so:

```
starttime = time.clock()
asyncio.wait_for((method()), 5)
endtime = time.clock()
print(endtime - starttime)
```

This usually results in Python spitting out something around 6.29989986222767E-06 (or 0.00000629989986222767E). Then I tried it with a time.sleep:

```
starttime = time.clock()
asyncio.wait_for((time.sleep(3)), 5)
endtime = time.clock()
print(endtime - starttime)
```

This again resulted in 6.87261802845284E-06, even though (at least I think) it should take 3 seconds. I have tried this using threads, with the same result. What do you think? How can I measure how long it takes for a function to run and complete?

Comment: The ```time``` module will be inaccurate because it depends on the cpu (will go slower at higher cpu usage), use the ```timeit``` module instead

Comment: use the timeit module https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: What is your goal in using `asyncio.wait_for()` instead of calling `method()` directly?

Comment: Attempt to try and measure the time taken for the method to finish. But it must be measuring the time taken to call the method, because a 3 second delay doesn't take 0.00000629989986222767E seconds to call and finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use this decorator to time my functions:

```
import time                                                
def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()
        print '%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \
              (method.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
        return result

    return timed

@timeit
def timeme():
    time.sleep(3)
```

`time.time()` gives more precise time for benchmarks than `time.clock()` primarily because `time.clock()` measures CPU time. `time.time()` will return seconds passed since epoch (i.e. wall time), which is what you need.

Or you can also use `timeit` https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 2):

For quick performance analyses I use the following two lines (plus imports):

```py
import time
import numpy as np

t = time.time()
# ...
print np.round_(time.time() - t, 3), 'sec elapsed'
```

It's short, simple and all I usually need.

(In most cases I've imported `numpy` anyway. So thats no overhead for me.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit that I'm not very familiar with Python's asyncio, but I believe the issue is not in your timing, but in your useage of `asyncio`.

I think you are just creating a future with the value of method(), however that is all that you are timing: the actual creation of this promise.

You are not timing the actual evaluation of the future value. This is why timing sleep(3) and method() take roughly the same amount of time.

I suggest trying to change `asyncio.wait_for((method()), 5)` with `yield from asyncio.wait_for((method()), 3)` or just `timing method()` if you can.