# Summed area table without module python 3

Tags: python, numpy, sum

Anyone know if there is a method to create a summed area table(SAT) without module??
I have try this and work:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 4))

print (A)
print(A.cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1))
```

but this is with module numpy.

Comment: do some research before asking question. I found the answer on the first google search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557973/efficient-summed-area-table-calculation-with-numpy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient summed Area Table Calculation with Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557973/efficient-summed-area-table-calculation-with-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [99]: A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 4))
In [100]: A
Out[100]: 
array([[1, 4, 0, 9],
       [5, 5, 3, 0],
       [3, 2, 1, 2]])
In [101]: A.cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)
Out[101]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  5, 14],
       [ 6, 15, 18, 27],
       [ 9, 20, 24, 35]])
```

`itertools` has an `accumulate` tool that behaves like `cumsum`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions

```
In [102]: from itertools import accumulate
In [103]: Al = A.tolist()
In [105]: [list(accumulate(row)) for row in Al]
Out[105]: [[1, 5, 5, 14], [5, 10, 13, 13], [3, 5, 6, 8]]
In [106]: [list(accumulate(row)) for row in zip(*_)]
Out[106]: [[1, 6, 9], [5, 15, 20], [5, 18, 24], [14, 27, 35]]
In [107]: list(zip(*_))
Out[107]: [(1, 5, 5, 14), (6, 15, 18, 27), (9, 20, 24, 35)]
```

Or packed into one expression:

```
In [109]: list(zip(*
     ...:    (accumulate(row) for row in zip(*
     ...:    (accumulate(row) for row in Al)))))
     ...:     
Out[109]: [(1, 5, 5, 14), (6, 15, 18, 27), (9, 20, 24, 35)]
```

If you can't use `itertools` either, then use `rough equivalent` generator given on the documentation page.

Or with this little accumulate function:

```
def accum(alist):
    total = 0; res = []
    for a in alist:
        total += a
        res.append(total)
    return res

In [111]: list(zip(*
     ...:    (accum(row) for row in zip(*
     ...:    (accum(row) for row in Al)))))  
Out[111]: [(1, 5, 5, 14), (6, 15, 18, 27), (9, 20, 24, 35)]
```