# Saving return value from python timeit function

Tags: python, time

`timeit.timeit()` seems to eat the function return value whole, and although you are able to print the value - saving the return value to a variable is not allowed.

eg.

```
data = None
time = timeit(lambda: data = function_invocation, number=1)
```

Can this be achieved with `timeit`?

Comment: The helper function swallows it, but you can use the method directly: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit

Comment: The point of timeit is to time the repeated execution of a function. If you just want to know how long a call takes, you can compare ˋtime.time()ˋ before and after the call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring the time it takes for a function to run and complete in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351083/measuring-the-time-it-takes-for-a-function-to-run-and-complete-in-python)